# how can I show more than 15 significant digits for each entry in matlab?

Tags: matlab, format, numbers, digits

I want to calculate numbers in Matlab.
how can I show more than 15 significant digits for each entry in Matlab?

```
a = 1:10;
x = (773712524553590618513 + (a * 8864385670));
```

Comment: Where do these digits come from? What do you need the additional precision for? Are you only interested in integer arithmetic? Please [edit] your question to clarify, the answer below might or might not be the best solution depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

Using the vpa function in the Symbolic Math Toolbox more than 16 digits can be shown.

```
format long e
a=1:10;
x = (773712524553590618513+(a*8864385670));
vpa(x)
```

Edit: Any clarification between the implications of using `syms` against `variable-point-precision (vpa)` for `a, 773712524553590618513 and 8864385670` in this case is much appreciated. Seems that using `vpa()` on each item would have some error propagation.

```
a = sym(1:10);
f = sym(773712524553590618513)+(a*sym(8864385670));
Significant_Digits = 32;
x = vpa(f,Significant_Digits)
```

Comment: You need to do the computations using VPA. Your code here computes to 15 digits (actually 52 binary digits) then displays additional digits based off the base-10 conversion of the binary representation. Those extra digits are meaningless.

Comment: Thank you, for the clarification. Makes sense since the precision of the final answer will always be constrained by variables used in the calculation. I'll try to format all the variables used in the calculation.

Comment: `sym(7)` reads in 7 as a double, then converts to symbolic representation. I think that `sym('7')` does the trick, but I have literally 0 experience with the symbolic toolbox, so don’t take my word for it.

Comment: Also, in case OP wants to do integer arithmetic only, this might be a good alternative to VPA: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic